# C++ universal reference parameter not binding to my variable

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, perfect-forwarding

I wrote a piece of C++ code for testing, it is pretty ugly(?), using a flexible array, but that's not the issue... I read that in templates, parameters like T&& can bind to anything really, like `MyData&`, `MyData&&` and `const MyData&`.

But in the following, even if I do send a `MyData` object which I think should be inferred as sending a `MyData&` to the function `create_variable`

Here's the function template:

```
template <typename T>
Variable<T>& create_variable(Variable<T>* next, T&& data) {
    auto buf = (Variable<T>*) new char[sizeof(Variable<T>) + sizeof(data)];
    buf->_next = next;
    uintptr_t buf_addr = (uintptr_t) ((char*)buf + sizeof(Variable<T>));
    assert(buf_addr % alignof(T) == 0);
    new ((void*)(buf->_data_buf)) T(std::forward<T>(data));
    return *buf;
}
```

And here's the call:

`Variable<MyData>& v = create_variable<MyData>(nullptr, m);`

And the full program:

```
#include <new>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>

template <typename T>
struct Variable {
    struct Variable<T>* _next;
    T _data_buf[];

    Variable() = delete;

    Variable(Variable<T>&& other) = delete;

    T get_data() {
        return _data_buf[0];
    }

    void print() {
        _data_buf[0].print();
    }
};

/// Create a Variable struct with both a next pointer and an inner T data
template <typename T>
Variable<T>& create_variable(Variable<T>* next, T&& data) {
    auto buf = (Variable<T>*) new char[sizeof(Variable<T>) + sizeof(data)];
    buf->_next = next;
    uintptr_t buf_addr = (uintptr_t) ((char*)buf + sizeof(Variable<T>));
    assert(buf_addr % alignof(T) == 0);
    new ((void*)(buf->_data_buf)) T(std::forward<T>(data));
    return *buf;
}
/// Create a Variable struct without the inner T data
template <typename T>
Variable<T>& create_variable(Variable<T>* next) {
    auto buf = (Variable<T>*) new char[sizeof(Variable<T>)];
    buf->_next = next;
    return *buf;
}

/// Test data-type
struct MyData {
    long health;
    long mana;
    MyData (const MyData& other) : health(other.health), mana(other.mana) {}
    MyData (MyData&& other) : health(other.health), mana(other.mana) {}
    MyData(int h, int m) : health(h), mana(m) {}
    void print() { std::cout << "Data: " << health << ',' << mana << ',' << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "Sizeof Variable<MyData> = " << sizeof(Variable<MyData>) << std::endl;
    MyData m(1, 2);
    Variable<MyData>& v = create_variable<MyData>(nullptr, m);
    v.print();
}
```

With the error I get from clang:

```
main.cpp:9:7: warning: flexible array members are a C99 feature [-Wc99-extensions]

    T _data_buf[];

      ^

main.cpp:9:7: warning: flexible array members are a C99 feature [-Wc99-extensions]

main.cpp:43:47: note: in instantiation of template class 'Variable<MyData>' requested here    

        std::cout << "Sizeof Variable<MyData> = " << sizeof(Variable<MyData>) << std::endl;

                                                 ^

main.cpp:45:24: error: no matching function for call to 'create_variable'

        Variable<MyData>& v = create_variable<MyData>(nullptr, m);

                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

main.cpp:20:14: note: candidate function [with T = MyData] not viable: no known conversion from 'MyData' to 'MyData &&' for 2nd argument

Variable<T>& create_variable(Variable<T>* next, T&& data) {

         ^

main.cpp:29:14: note: candidate function template not viable: requires single argument     'next', but 2 arguments were provided

Variable<T>& create_variable(Variable<T>* next) {

         ^

2 warnings and 1 error generated.
```

Comment: Since you *explicitly specify* the template argument, it cannot be deduced any longer. And deduction is necessary to make an rvalue-reference a *forwarding reference*.

Comment: @dyp I see. So when I do `Variable<MyData>& v = create_variable(nullptr, m);` , it still fails and complains that it expects the types Variable<T>* and nullptr_t. Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: You can either use your current definition of `create_variable` and call it via `create_variable(static_cast<Variable<MyData>*>(nullptr), m)` or any similar variation like `Variable<MyData>* n = nullptr; create_variable(n, m);` or you change your definition and decouple the deduction of `T` from the first argument.

Comment: Hmm. I don't really understand why you've implemented `create_variable` or `Variable<T>` the way you did. From what I can understand, something like `template<typename T, typename U> Variable<T>& create_variable(Variable<T>*, U&&)` (possibly plus a check to make sure that `decay_t<U>` is the same as `T`) might make more sense than changing the way it's called.

Comment: This looks like a linked list where each node *can* contain data?

Comment: @dyp I might be wrong, but I think for the first argument of the `create_variable` function, one needs `T` to be deduced to `MyData`, but for the second argument, one needs it to be `MyData &`. Which are in conflict. I don't think `T&&` will bind to `MyData`. Will it?

Comment: @yzt True. So the only viable solution is to decouple it.

Comment: @slnsoumik If you want a linked list where each node has minimal memory footprint and *may* or *may not* contain data, you can write something probably easier: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9878d570b8bf9c9

Comment: @dyp actually I was writing a redblack tree implementation, the book uses a dummy node as the null node. Using a nullptr complicates things, but I didn't want to allocate extra memory for the dummy node's key and value fields. So I am trying to see if it's possible without forcing the key and value fields to be pointers to data i.e the user can just move/copy key and value into the node if they want. The dummy node's key and value won't be needed. So this example is sort of same, the key (no value here) being the _data_buf.

Comment: Ah, your linked list does look nice. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @slnsoumik I think I just had a better idea. What I posted earlier has issues with destruction and non-standard-layout data. I'll write up an example..

Comment: [That's a bit nicer](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1fe67c561309eaac). And with either a virtual destructor (+8 bytes per node) or a bool/bit-twiddling and some additional logic, you can even reasonably simply destruct the nodes.

Comment: This is awesome! CRTP and variadic templates for the win! Love it. Thanks.

Comment: I see no CRTP there, though. o.O

Comment: Uhh.. wait sorry. That's not CRTP. I am still getting started with proper C++(been writing C-style C++ before this) and coming across a lot of terms, it gets confusing and hard to remember so many features, patterns and idioms. :P